# How to create Dynamic partition with sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I read from sqoop documentation

- http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_hcatalog_background

> 23.6. Support for Partitioning The Sqoop HCatalog feature supports the following table types:
>
> Unpartitioned tables Partitioned tables with a static partitioning key
>   specified Partitioned tables with dynamic partition keys from the
>   database result set Partitioned tables with a combination of a static
>   key and additional dynamic partitioning keys

But I am not getting how to use dynamic partition using sqoop.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
--username root
--password-file file:///home/hdfs/.password
--split-by id
--table test 
--delete-target-dir
--fields-terminated-by ","
--hcatalog-table test
--hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile"
--create-hcatalog-table
--hcatalog-partition-keys created_at
--map-column-hive created_at=date,updated_at=date
```

But I'm getting this error...

> Either both --hcatalog-partition-keys and --hcatalog-partition-values
>   should be provided or both of these options should be omitted.

If I use `--hcatalog-partition-values`, then it assigns it as static partition.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
--username root
--password-file file:///home/hdfs/.password
--split-by id
--table test 
--delete-target-dir
--fields-terminated-by ","
--hcatalog-table test
--hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile"
--create-hcatalog-table
--hcatalog-partition-keys created_at
--hcatalog-partition-value created_at
--map-column-hive created_at=date,updated_at=date
```

after giving `created_at` as `hcatalog-partition-value` it created the directory like: `apps/hive/warehouse/test/created_at=created_at`

It should have used `created_at` column to create dynamic partition based on data.

Please help me fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: any luck on this? i also have same question